# show a list of pages in refineryCMS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refinerycms

I´m trying to generate a list of pages based on their parent page if any as a parameter.

When I run the code in the rails console it works.

but in the view I'm getting "undefined method each" and is outputting nil.

I´ve followed the this tutorial:
http://refinerycms.com/guides/using-custom-view-or-layout-templates#create-a-custom-action

here is my code:
https://gist.github.com/c69aa0a62d5936df00e5

what am I missing?.

Comment: Please , provide all the log with errors . The most usual problem is that the method `each` is called on a nil object .